# Internet Explorer em modo de compatibilidade para sites da Intranet - Como forçar para sempre renderizar como Edge?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Tenho um site que disponibilizei para usuários internos em uma intranet para homologação.

Porém usuários que testaram com o Internet Explorer 11 estavam com o site sendo renderizado no "Modo de Exibição de Compatibilidade", pois o Internet Explorer verifica que o site está na Intranet e por padrão está configurado para renderizar nesse modo de compatibilidade. Entendo que esse modo é mais apropriado para sites antigos, no caso o IE renderiza com compatibilidade para o IE7!

Sei que é possível mudar essa configuração no Internet Explorer, em Configurações -> Configurações do Modo de Exibição de Compatibilidade, desmarcando a opção "Exibir sites da intranet no Modo de Exibição de Compatibilidade", conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou também posso mudar o modo pela "Ferramentas para desenvolvedores F12" , conforme figura abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas a pergunta é: "Como forçar para que a página sempre seja exibida no modo  Edge, ou seja o mais recente?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque a seguinte *meta tag*, **logo após** a tag `<title>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

[Fonte](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible)

Comment: Maravilha. O Internet Explorer agora está renderizando corretamente no modo Edge.